# Arabic WordNet with not-formatted words

Tags: nlp, arabic, wordnet

Is it necessary for the word input to WordNet to be formatted like "التُّفَّاحْ" and can't expect "التفاح"...
is there any library or service taking not-formatted Arabic word returning a list of all its possible synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

From `التُّفَّاحْ` to `التفاح`, you simply want to remove the diacritics then you need a lexical normalization tool. Try [Tashaphyne](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tashaphyne/), download and install then use the `normalize` module http://pythonhosted.org/Tashaphyne/Tashaphyne.normalize-module.html :

```
from Tashaphyne import *

text = 'التُّفَّاحْ'
print normalize_hamza(text)
print normalize_lamalef(text)
print normalize_searchtext(text)
```

Comment: Both words are plural. One is with diacritics, the other is without.

Comment: it's not Farsi, it's Arabic

Comment: pardon my mistake. yes, if it's only diacritic, then it's simple.