# Using Arabic WordNet for synonyms in python?

Tags: python, nlp, arabic

I am trying to get the synonyms for arabic words in a sentence

If the word is in English it works perfectly, and the results are displayed in Arabic language, I was wondering if its possible to get the synonym of an Arabic word right away without writing it in english first.

I tried that but it didn't work & I would prefer without tashkeel انتظار instead of اِنْتِظار

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as omw
jan = omw.synsets('انتظار ')[0]
print(jan)
print(jan.lemma_names(lang='arb'))
```

Comment: It's an old answer but tell me if it doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096559/arabic-wordnet-with-not-formatted-words

Comment: no I tried it but it didn't work at all

Comment: The nltk now provides the Open Multilingual Wordnet, which includes Arabic. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156965/nltk-omw-wordnet-with-arabic-language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordnet used in nltk doesnt support arabic. If you are looking for [Arabic Wordnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522161/import-arabic-wordnet-in-python?lq=1) so this is  a totally different thing.

For Arabic wordnet, download:

- http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/get_bd.php
- http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/awn/AWNDatabaseManagement.py.gz

You run it with:

```
$ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml
```

---

Now to get something like `wn.synset('إنتظار')`. Arabic Wordnet has a function `wn.get_synsets_from_word(word)`, but it gives offsets. Also it accepts the words only as vocalized in the database. For example, you should use `جَمِيل` for `جميل`:

```
>> wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
[(u'a', u'300218842')]
```

`300218842` is the offset of the synset of جميل .

I checked for the word إنتظار and seems it doesn't exist in AWN.

More details about using AWN to get synonyms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522161/import-arabic-wordnet-in-python?lq=1).

Comment: When I run it using $ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml
I got :  <open file 'upc_db.xml', mode 'r' at 0x10156c270>

but when I wrote: wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل") I got
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/InjySarhan/PycharmProjects/28Dec/AWNDatabaseManagement.py", line 398, in <module>
    opts = processCmdlineOpts(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/InjySarhan/PycharmProjects/28Dec/AWNDatabaseManagement.py", line 320, in processCmdlineOpts
    if not opts.has_key('i'):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: run it using python2 not python3

Comment: I just tried it using python 2 ,  run it using $ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml I got : <open file 'upc_db.xml', mode 'r' at 0x10156c270> but when I wrote: 
Synset('delay.n.01')
[u'\u0627\u0650\u0646\u0652\u062a\u0650\u0638\u0627\u0631', u'\u062a\u0623\u062c\u0650\u064a\u0644', u'\u062a\u0623\u062e\u0650\u064a\u0631', u'\u062a\u0648\u0642\u0651\u064f\u0641']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects20Dec.py" line 492, in <module>
   wn.get_synsets_from_word("جَمِيل")
AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word'

Comment: write `wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")`  inside`AWNDatabaseManagement.py ` at the end  and execute it.

Comment: I followed ur answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522161/import-arabic-wordnet-in-python/29545179#29545179 but always get the same error

Comment: write `wn.get_synsets_from_word(u"جَمِيل")`  inside`AWNDatabaseManagement.py ` at the end  and execute it. The same for all instructions. If it worked, we'll discuss how to execute from a different place.

Comment: when I did that and ran it again $ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml I got: line 407 non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file AWNDatabaseManagement.py on line 407, but no encoding declared

Comment: @I.Abdelsalam add this as a second line in the top `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` and re-run

Comment: AWNDatabaseManagement.py ran when I added # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-, but when I run when i run the original file still the same error AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'get_synsets_from_word

Comment: you are still using `wn` of `nltk`, dont do. use the `wn` inside the `AWNDatabaseManagement.py `, what  code you are running?

Comment: Please mark this as accepted, and ask the new issue as a new question then send me link I will give you a clear answer.

Comment: done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820968/arabic-word-net-synonyms-in-python thanks

Comment: @bigOTHER you say: "Wordnet used in nltk doesnt support arabic." but it does in 3rd version using [Open Multilingual Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/). [sample](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/nltk-users/estFavchR34)

Comment: @ARZ Thanks for letting me know

Comment: This answer is out of date. The nltk now includes a version of the Open Multilingual Wordnet that includes Arabic.