# Use Arabic WordNet to get Arabic synonyms?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, arabic

How can I install AWN on Python,  to use Arabic synonyms?

I have AWNDatabaseManagement.py and the file awn.xml, what would my next step be?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620627/using-arabic-wordnet-for-synonyms-in-python) but I need more details

I found this code and I don't know what is it

```
from AWNDatabaseManagement import wn

synsets = wn.get_synsetids_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
for s in synsets:
wn._items[s].describe()
```

Comment: Please, i need help, i want to run this : $ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml   but i dont know how :/

Answer (score 0):

You should put both files in the same folder than call the command:

```
$ python AWNDatabaseManagement.py -i upc_db.xml
```

You can also change the line 320 in order to import it as a library in python:

```
opts['i']='E:/usuaris/horacio/arabicWN/AWNdatabase/upc_db.xml'
```

to

```
opts['i']='upc_db.xml'
```

After this you can import it:

```
from AWNDatabaseManagement import awn
```

The next commands show how to get synsets of a word and iterate through them.

```
synsets = awn.get_synsetids_from_word(u"جَمِيل")
for s in synsets:
    wn._items[s].describe()
```

Comment: I did the first step, and i get this : can't find __main__ module in 'AWNDatabaseManagement.py' , so what should i do ? And i have to change the line 320 ? and i would know the import should be in the (AWNDatabaseManagement.py) ? so i'm little lost.