# Arabic WordNet Specifications

Tags: nlp, arabic, wordnet, open-multilingual-wordnet

Is there any documentation or tutorial for Arabic WordNet? either for this 
 [Arabic WordNet](http://globalwordnet.org/arabic-wordnet/) or from the [Open Multilingual Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/).

The answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620627/using-arabic-wordnet-for-synonyms-in-python) shows an example, but I want a full description such as in [English WordNet](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html).

Thanks.